# Kohana 3.2 ORM Does not contain model info

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm working with Kohana 3.2 and have the following code in my controller.

```
  $Blog_Post = new Model_Blogpost();

  $Blog_Post->where('id', '=', 1);
  $Blog_Post->find();

  $content = $Blog_Post->content;
```

I Currently have 3 records in my db with id's 1, 2, and 3.

$Blog_Post->content, or any other field return null. and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `ORM::factory('blogpost', $id)` or `new Model_Blogpost($id)` if you need an object with PK == $id.
2. Check your model after loading.

> ```
>   if $Blog_Post->loaded()
>   {
>        // it works!
>   }
>   else
>   {
>        // record not found
>   }
> ```

If record not found, you can see last DB query with `$Blog_Post->last_query()`

**UPD**. From comments. Your model will not work with this modifications. Note that ORM data stored in `$_object` property, and `$Blog_Post->content` is just a shortcut for `$Blog_Post->_object['content']` via `__get()` method. Of course, if you define public `$content` property, `$Blog_Post->content` will return NULL value instead of using DB data.

There is no reason for defining model fields as properties. If you need IDE hints, just use PHPDOC.

Comment: This is very odd, I had use the factory in the past, but that didn't worked either. I also used "new Model_Blogpost($id)" and checked that the object was loaded, and it was!! yet I still got back null for $Blog_Post->content. A closer look to the object shows that _object does contain the model info http://d.pr/fY99 but all the actual fields that get called are empty.

Comment: It looks like you have incorrect modifications in your Model. Can you paste it somewhere (pastebin.com for example)?

Comment: You are right! the issue was in how I was defining my model. the issue being that I was re-declaring each table field with in my model http://d.pr/Xp5B. As I test/learn the framework I have been doing different things. I guess the simpler the models the better? If you edit your answer I'll mark it as the correct one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: ORM models are not so simple as you think ;) Answer was updated.

Answer (score 0):

At the firm I work for we were looking into upgrading to 3.2 very recently. However, in our evaluation I don't recall seeing a difference in ORM handling methods.
Yours above looks like it should be something like this:

```
  $Blog_Post = ORM::factory('blogpost')->where('id', '=', 1)->find();

  $content = $Blog_Post->content;
```

Assuming your table is called blogposts, of course. I may be wrong about that and if I am, can you link to the documentation that shows this kind of model interaction?

Comment: Actually the factory returns a new Model, that is why you can do cascade method calling. As far as I know you line of code and my three lines of code are equivalent. Now you do bring up a good point. when talking about the name of the table. my table is called blog_post and not blogpost. Although I have a variable in my model "protected $_table_name  = 'blog_post';" which should tell the model what table I'm using. I think I'm in the same spot :(